# Qt - Puerto serie sobre windows responde pero sobre linux no!

Tags: c++, qt, serialport, usb

recurro a uds porque tengo un problema leyendo el puerto serie. Resulta que mi demo se ejecuta correctamente sobre windows pero no obtengo ningun tipo de respuesta sobre linux. El dispositivo al cual me conecto es una antena, a la cual hay que enviarle el comando "log gpgga ontime 1" + el retorno de carro. Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
void MainWindow::on_btnObtener_clicked()
{
    foreach(const QSerialPortInfo &info, QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts())
    {

        qDebug() << "Puerto: " << info.portName();
        qDebug() << "Nro. Serie: " << info.serialNumber();
        qDebug() << "Fabricante: " << info.manufacturer();
        qDebug() << "Descripcion: " << info.description();

        if (info.portName().trimmed().compare("ttyUSB0") == 0)
        {
            auxserial = new QSerialPort(info);
            auxserial->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
            connect(auxserial, &QSerialPort::readyRead, this, &MainWindow::readData);

            if (auxserial->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
            {
                const QByteArray buffer = "log gprmc ontime 1";
                auxserial->write(buffer);
                auxserial->flush();

                const QByteArray fin = "\r\n";
                auxserial->write(fin);

                auxserial->flush();
                qInfo() << "Puerto Abierto correctamente";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

void MainWindow::readData()
{
    while(auxserial->canReadLine())
        qInfo() << auxserial->readLine();
}
```

Ahora bien, sobre windows funciona correctamente e incluso, si adrede le escribo mal el comando, me devuelve la respuesta de la antena con un mensaje de error emitido por la antena. 
SIN EMBARGO DESDE LINUX, no sucede nada de esto...me dice que el puerto está abierto correctamente, pero no responde ni OK ni ERROR. Que puede estar pasando?

EDIT: acabo de descubrir que hay linux que tienen problemas con el adaptador "CH341 USB Adapter"...en este caso estoy usando un Debian 9

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya encontré la solucion...evidentemente el problema era el adaptador CH340-341, dado que en algunas distros linux anda bien y en otras no, por un problema de paridad en el driver. En el video del link, se explica como solucionarlo. A mi me funcionó, espero que otros que tengan el mismo problema puedan solucionarlo.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Yun14QscDs

Gracias